# Is "inet addr" my or "bcast" my machine's actual IP?

Tags: networking, ip, ifconfig

I'm trying to connect from one machine to the other (for Postgres), and I'm confused about how to configure my IP address, both from a `allow connections from IP address X` and from a `connect to machine A on IP address X` standpoint, assuming there could be a difference.

If I use `ifconfig`, the output says my `bcast` is `10.0.2.255` and `inet addr` is `10.0.2.15`. A related query on this subject pertains to the selected answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/243965/how-to-grep-the-ip-address-from-ifconfig-output), wherein the use of `/24` (24 bit IP) in the actual IP address confuses me. How/when should `/24` be used when specifying an IP address?

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux. Use `ip addr` (or just `ip a`) instead.

Comment: @batchyx - would you please stop propogating this invalid information. I have seen this specific comment more than once and again, I must comment on how this is wrong.

Comment: @mdpc: http://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`10.0.2.15` is your system's address, `.255` is the broadcast address for the subnet.

`/24` is CIDR notation for the subnet mask; it means that 24 bits of the 32 bit IPv4 address are the network and the other 8 bits are the addresses within the subnet.

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for more information.